# AngularUI Bootstrap: Parse HTML in carousel text

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm trying to implement an [Angular UI Bootstrap Carousel](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel) and have HTML in the texts. Thought I could use something like

```
text: $sce.trustAsHtml('Nice image <br />test')
```

but apparently that doesn't work and I've no clue why.

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/9PvaS8SoRmN1o52wiAf8?p=preview (fork of the [offical example from the docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-bind-html` directive to display html content on view

```
<p ng-bind-html="slide.text"></p>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/R50Na7U9sQo7HB0fPoum?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!